# IndexedDB filled with Webpack bundled files

Tags: javascript, webpack, indexeddb, hot-module-replacement

While cleaning some stuff I found this folder: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\IndexedDB\devtools_devtools_0.indexeddb.blob\1` that had 5 GB of pure webpack bundles.

My problem is that most of it (if not all) was generated by my own projects that used webpack. Is this an Edge or a webpack hmr bug/feature. And if so, is there a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge DevTools caches loaded source maps for about 30 days. So, this folder should not keep growing forever.

You can clear the source map cache this way:

1. Open the **Command menu** with <kbd>Ctrl+shift+P</kbd> (replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> if you're on Mac).
2. Start typing the word "Clear" and choose the **Clear source maps cache** command, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: Screenshot of Edge DevTools, with the Command menu opened and showing the Clear source maps cache command]

Comment: It does not work - size stays the same. Also this folder contains files much older than 30 days